# Running into Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property of undefined

Tags: javascript, arrays, indexing, undefined, uncaught-exception

I have an algorithm that will modify a 10x10 2D array for a BattleShip game to randomly place ships down in a random direction.

The board looks like this:

```js
var board= [
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], // 0
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], // 1
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], // 2
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], // 3
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], // 4
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], // 5
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], // 6
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], // 7
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], // 8
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]  // 9
];
```

The algorithm will turn the 0's into 1's and place a random ship at a random index, and at a random direction. The array is like this: `var array = [5, 4, 3, 3, 2]` (The numbers represent the length e.g. five 1's, four 1's, etc.) The algorithm works good most times and will run until the array is empty.

The problem is, I keep occasionally running into `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property of <some integer> undefined` ONLY when trying to place the ship in either the UP or DOWN direction as it reaches out of bounds. The error occurs for the if statements that check if the direction chosen is out of bounds like so:

```js
// check out of bounds for UP direction
if (x - 1 < 0 || array[x - i][y] == undefined) {
  break;
}
```

```js
// check out of bounds for DOWN direction
if (x + 1 > 9 || array[x + i][y] == undefined) {
  break;
}
```

I believe the error is occurring with something to do with the negative index from trying to perform `array[x - i][y]` and `array[x + i][y]`. I thought I already fixed this by adding my additional OR check with `x - 1 < 0` and `x + 1 > 9` but still I am running into this exception.

Comment: What is `i`, is it also equal to `1`? If not, I think your bounds checks should be `x - i` and `x + y` instead.

Comment: `i` is part of the for loop that loops till the length of the chosen ship: `for (let i = 0; i < randShip; i++)`

Comment: Okay. So if `x` is 1 and `y` is 2 then your bounds check will not work correctly. `x - 1` in this case will be `0` but `x - i` would be `-1`.

Comment: Right, and wouldn't that lead to being equal to `undefined`?

Comment: Yes. However, when you say `array[x - i][y]` and `x - i` is `undefined`, you're going to get the `cannot read property of undedined` error. Why? Because `array[x - i]` results in `undefined`, thus you cannot access `[y]` of `undefined`. If that makes sense?

Comment: Hmm okay, that makes more sense. So I do need to perform a check specifically for the index I am evaluating individually? Like perhaps doing `if (array[x - i] == undefined)` BEFORE doing `array[x - i][y] == undefined`?

Comment: Correct. Check `x +/- 1` as well as `array[x +/- i]` first.

Comment: Thank you, that seemed to be the issue. Did you want to post an answer and I can mark it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per the comments, the problem is there is no bounds checking on `array[x + i]` and `array[x - i]`. Because of that, the calls to `array[x +/- i][y]` result in a `cannot read property ... of undefined` error.